# How to select all tags by XPath between the two tags if it needs to use relative path to the second tag

Tags: xml, xpath

I have such xml structure:

```
<orange attr="orangeXXX"/>

<apple attr="somedata" attr2="xxx"/>
<apple attr="somedata" attr2="yyy"/>
...
<apple attr="somedata" attr2="zzz"/>

<orange attr="orangeYYY"/>

<apple attr="somedata" attr2="aaa"/>
<apple attr="somedata" attr2="bbb"/>
...
<apple attr="somedata" attr2="ccc"/>

<orange attr="orangeZZZ"/>
```

I want to get all the tags between `<orange attr="orangeXXX"/>` and the next  tag after `<orange attr="orangeYYY"/>`:

```
<apple attr="somedata" attr2="xxx"/>
<apple attr="somedata" attr2="yyy"/>
...
<apple attr="somedata" attr2="zzz"/>
```

I created such XPath to get these tags:

```
/apple[@attr="somedata" and preceding-sibling::orange[@attr="orangeXXX"] 
                        and following-sibling::orange[@attr="orangeYYY"]]
```

The problem is that here I'm using direct attribute 'orangeYYY' but I want to avoid directly using of this attribute and use some relative constructions.

Is it possible to make such XPath which can grep these tags between `<orange attr="orangeXXX"/>` and `<orange attr="orangeYYY"/>` without using "orangeYYY" value at all?

Thank you!

Comment: Is restructuring the XML an option? That XML seems to totally miss the whole point of XML and its document structure.

Comment: What XPath version?  This is easy enough in XPath 2.0 but I'm not sure it can be done in a single XPath 1.0 expression.

Comment: @lonesomeday It's actually HTML and unfortunately there is no ability to change this structure for me since this structure is required for 3rd party service

Comment: @IanRoberts I'm afraid my 3rd party library (java xmlunit) based on 1.0 version

Comment: @lonesomeday Anyway it might help me if you give me example of solution for XPath 2.0 version

Comment: Calling it HTML is also quite optimistic. Both XML and HTML require structure. Angle brackets don't constitute XML and HTML! So XML/HTML functions are unlikely to facilitate what you want to do with the data.

Comment: @lonesomeday errm, it's actually just a part of the whole document, I believe the whole document doesn't matter here. Of course it has structure. I just created an analogue of my code. In my code I have standart html tags instead of 'apple' and 'root'

Comment: Fair enough. Calling a tag that isn't the root node `root` is at best counter-intuitive!

Comment: @lonesomeday My fail, just edited the question, yes, it shouldn't be called 'root'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way :

```
/apple[
        @attr="somedata" 
            and 
        preceding-sibling::orange[@attr="orangeXXX"] 
            and 
        count(following-sibling::orange)=count(preceding-sibling::orange[@attr="orangeXXX"]/following-sibling::orange)
      ]
```

The key is in the part after the 2nd `and` :

```
count(following-sibling::orange)=count(preceding-sibling::orange[@attr="orangeXXX"]/following-sibling::orange)
```

Above expression count number of `<orange>` siblings following current `<apple>` node, and only return those `<apple>`s which count equals number of `<orange>` siblings following the `orange[@attr="orangeXXX"]` node.

Comment: Great, it works! Pretty complicated to me, it seems I need to learn XPath more.